# Wildfly 21 – how to customize returns for Bean Validation exceptions

Tags: java, resteasy, bean-validation, java-ee-8, wildfly-21

I've tried registering custom exception mappers in multiple ways:

```
@Provider
public class ConstraintViolationMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ConstraintViolationException exception) {
        ...
    }
}

@Provider
public class ConstraintViolationMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ResteasyViolationException> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ResteasyViolationException exception) {
        ...
    }
}

@Provider
public class ConstraintViolationMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ValidationException> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ValidationException exception) {
        ...
    }
}
```

But all that happens is the default behaviour by the ResteasyViolationExceptionMapper. My custom ExceptionMapper is never called. I don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it didn't work when I first tried it, but this works

```
@Provider
public class ConstraintViolationMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ValidationException> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ValidationException exception) {
        ...
    }
}
```